# UIView animation issues with autolayout and constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

I'm developing an app which has a feature allowing the user to select an image from their photo library and attach a caption to it, for display in a UICollectionView. I'm using storyboards and autolayout. I have a UIView (embedded in a navigation controller) which holds a basic text field for the user to enter their caption, a button that initialises the image picker controller, and a small UIView subview which contains both a thumbnail of the image selected and a small 'X' button for when the user decides to change their selection.

When the user has made a selection I want an animation to hide the 'select image' button and move the UIView holding the image thumbnail up into it's place. If they then hit the 'X' button on the corner of the thumbnail, the UIView will move back down and the 'select image' button will reappear.

My problem is I can get the animation to work when the user **cancels** the selection, but not when they have **made** the selection and get returned from the image picker controller; the view doesn't move at all, yet to test the animation code I set the 'select image' button's alpha to 0.0 and this animates correctly!?

Here's some code:

```
// MyController.m

// When user hits the 'select image' button
- (void)selectImage
{   
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// When user has selected an image from photo library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Grab photo selection..

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
    [self imageSelectionMade];
}

// Animation to hide button and move thumbnail up
- (void)imageSelectionMade
{
    CGRect rect = self.thumbView.frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.buttonView.alpha = 0;
        self.thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, (rect.origin.y - 76), rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    }completion:nil];
    // Show 'X' button on corner of image
}

// Animation to move thumbnail down and display button again
- (void)imageSelectionCancelled
{
    CGRect rect = self.thumbView.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.buttonView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, (rect.origin.y + 76), rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    }];
    // Change image to 'placeholder' and hide 'X' button..
}
```

I've read a lot of different posts on here regarding similar issues to this but none seem to solve the problem. I've tried manipulating the view's constraints instead of the view's frame which just causes it to 'snap' into place in both instances. I've tried `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`which has no effect. I've tried putting the code for the first animation just **before** the image picker appears which works, but obviously gets covered by the picker coming into view. I'm afraid to say I don't know what else to try short of disabling autolayout (which I'm not overly confident doing given my limited experience and the face that I don't really know how it will affect the rest of the application)

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I can only guess it's related to the constraints of the subview, but then why does it work in my `imageSelectionCancelled`method?

Note: I'm using Xcode 4.6

Comment: I am not sure your description fully conveys the problem, yet I would adopt a basic practice, which is canceling any animation before starting a new one. In this case I would add these lines in both in imageSelectionCancelled and imageSelectionMade, before starting the animations.:
    [self.buttonView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [self. thumbView.layer removeAllAnimations];

Comment: Thanks @TalYaniv, there's still no animation the first time I select an image, but if I cancel that selection and pick again it seems to work perfectly every time, until I return to the collection view in which case the process repeats. Is there anything you suggest I add to my post to better describe the problem?

Comment: I think that the code you quote is not full and was not tested. It actually contains an uncommented line ("Grab photo selection.."). Also I am not sure you really meant to dismiss the entire View Controller when an image was picked, in imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:. Maybe this got me confusing.

Comment: @TalYaniv, the code is most certainly tested. 'Grab photo selection' represents the code for handling the image returned by the picker - those few lines of code are irrelevant to the problem so I put a comment instead, I just forgot to comment the line (fixed now). As for `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, that dismisses the `UIImagePickerViewController` so yes, I meant it. Once the user has made their selection I don't see why I wouldn't dismiss it?